# C# форма и 2 tcpserver

Tags: c#

Нужен совет реализации след структуры. 
1) форма
2)  поток с таймером. Каждые 10 сек обновляет данные массива объектов (запись)
3) первый поток с tcp сервером обрабатывает запросы на одном порту. И возвращает инфу с мисива объектов ( только чтение) 
4) второй поток с tcp сервером возвращает инфу с массива в другом формате (чтение)

Как более корректно реализовать. И можно было с формы смотреть статистику на tcp сервах ? Буду очень благодарен

Comment: Если вам нужен только совет, то я бы посоветовал начать писать код, и когда появятся проблемы с кодом, тогда спрашивать. Архитектуру решения вам никто не подскажет, только вы можете знать, как вам лучше решить вашу задачу. А вот если проблемы с конкретным кодом будут - welcome

Comment: Есть клас с сервером. Как запустить поток что бы с формы был доступ к переменным класа. И поток так же имел доступ к переменным класса и массиву  формы

Comment: Я вас не пойму. Вот вы задали сверху вопрос - если вы хотите его дополнить/поправить, то делайте это. Если вы хотите задать новый вопрос - задавайте отдельным вопросом. Если вам нужна помощь с формулировкой вопроса - [ознакомьтесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), если вы что то спрашиваете по конкретному коду - приведите [минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), если вся ваша проблема в том, что вы из фонового потока не моежете обратиться к форме и UI компонентам в ней - используйте диспетчер.

Comment: попробуйте сделать от простого к сложному. сделайте форму. добавьте таймер с 10 секундами, пускай он выводит на форму какой-нибудь текст, подключитесь к серверу и т.д. идея в том что не думать больше чем над одной проблемой одновременно, а решать их последовательно

Answer (score 0):

Какой-такой поток? async-ом, что ли, запускаете? Так передавайте функции потока в аргументах то, к чему требуется доступ. Хотя если всё в одном классе, то и передавать не надо, всё и так доступно из любой функции. Только используйте concurent версии массивов.